# A question regarding integration

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f\ge0 ,\forall x\in [0,\infty), f$ is monotonic decreasing and 
$\int_{0}^\infty f(x)$ converges. Does it mean that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$?

I think I got to understanding that the statement is correct. My idea is to prove by contradiction that if  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)\ne0$ then the integral doesn't converge. I'm stuck in how to show that with the given data.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=l>0$. Since $f$ is monotonic decreasing you have $f(x)\geq l,\forall x$. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)\ne0$, then there is an $\epsilon > 0$ for which $\forall x\in [0,\infty), f(x) \ge \epsilon$ (because $f$ is monotonically decreasing). That means $\int_0^N f(x)dx \ge \int_0^N \epsilon dx = N\epsilon$, and the limit of this when $N$ goes to $\infty$ is undefined (because this $N$ can be chosen arbitrarily high; it does not depend on $\epsilon$). Therefore, the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ does not converge.